# Can you help me figure out this band?

Tags: computer-puzzle

So, that [super cool coworker of mine](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/40633/staff-party-can-i-go?s=1|1.8665) was impressed at how I got the password to the staff party. I didn't tell him I got help from you guys, though, so he's given me another challenge! Instead of his favorite movie, he wants me to guess his favorite band. This time, an invitation to his house to play Overwatch is on the line. All he gave me was a [link to a Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/cepenUvs) and a note that says "em pay tress". Can you help me name the band he asked for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is:

> The pastebin is base64 encoded data. The note "em pay tres" is MP3 and means it's an MP3. Decoding it and playing it yields a track with Morse code which decodes to "WE ARE, WE ARE, THE YOUTH OF THE NATION", and so the answer is P.O.D.
>
>  If you're curious: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CSCQuN_Ox9s

Amusingly...

> I spent an inordinate amount of time trying to find a working online morse code audio decoder before I just submitted to taking the 10 seconds to type in the dots and dashes, heh.

Comment: Good job! I like your effort of trying to find an audio decoder :P.

Comment: Good old Morse code, heh?